# Dynamically adjust recyclerview item's height

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a hands free device right now, and I'm having issues with scrolling. I don't know how they measure how much they are going to scroll, so I need items in a recyclerview to fit flush in the screen. Meaning, I might want 3 items per page, and everytime I "scroll" down with the device, the next 3 items show flush without being cut off. Is there anyway to dynamically adjust the items so that none of them are cut off on the screen when "scrolling". I've tried getting the height of the recyclerview and dividing by 3 and making that the height of each item. However, on this device, it seems that everytime I "scroll", the items become less and less flush, and more cutoff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination technique 
split ur items into groups and each group have only three items.
let say u have 30 items so split it into 10 groups and each group have a key like page number so when it open for the first time u'll display page 1 which contains 3 items and by scrolling and using endless Scroll u'll display page 2 and so on.

this how to split items

```
 int pageNumbers = (int) Math.ceil(items.size() / 3.0);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumbers; i++) {
                if (i == 1)
                    firstIndex = 0;
                else
                    firstIndex += 3;
                lastIndex=firstIndex+3;
                ArrayList<String> itemsPerPage=new ArrayList<>();

                for (int j = firstIndex; j < lastIndex; j++)
                {
                 itemsPerPage.add(items.get(j));   
                }
                    pages.put(i, items);
            }
```

now you have a HashMap with items per page and by implementing onSrollListener with recyclerView you can update page and get like : page=2 which contains 3 items and display the new 3 items with recycler